# Como puedo "inhabilitar" un EditText para que solo funcione en el modo horizontal?

Tags: java, android-studio, edittext

Tengo una app que hace 4 operaciones distintas (Suma, Resta, Divide, Multiplica) 2 números, algo básico, y cuando se pone en modo horizontal se cambia a 3 números, mi problema es que como el mismo código de Java se utiliza para las 2 ventanas, en la ventana vertical no hace nada, en cambio en la horizontal sí, pero aparece en el texto que inserte en el `xml` de la ventana vertical.

Sé que **el problema es el EditText** pero no sé como solucionarlo.

Mi profesor dijo que debemos hacerlo sin utilizar 2 actividades distintas de Java, ni tampoco utilizando códigos que reconozcan la orientación del dispositivo.

Código del `EditText` de la `activity_main.xml`(modo vertical)

```
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/ThirthNum"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="Escribe el tercer numero"
    android:text="This is a Test"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
```

Código del `EditText` de la `land/activity_main.xml`(modo horizontal).

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ThirthNum"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Tercer numero"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
```

Clase Java, espero se pueda entender que es lo que quiero hacer.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    TextView Result;
    EditText Num1;
    EditText Num2;
    EditText Num3;
    Button Suma;
    Button Resta;
    Button Multi;
    Button Divi;
    TextView IM1;
    TextView IM2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Result);
        Num1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.FirstNum);
        Num2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.SecondNum);
        Num3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ThirthNum);
        Suma = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnplus);
        Resta = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnminus);
        Multi = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMult);
        Divi = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDivi);
        IM1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.iconMark1);
        IM2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.iconMark2);

        Suma.setOnClickListener(this);
        Resta.setOnClickListener(this);
        Multi.setOnClickListener(this);
        Divi.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            String Dif = "This is a Test";
            if (v.getId() == R.id.btnplus) {
                IM1.setText("+");
                IM2.setText("+");

                int R1 = Integer.parseInt(Num1.getText().toString());
                int R2 = Integer.parseInt(Num2.getText().toString());
                String R3 = (Num3.getText().toString());

                if ((Num3.getText().toString()) != Dif){
                int R4 = Integer.parseInt(R3);
                int RT = R1 + R2 + R4;
                Result.setText(String.valueOf(RT));
                }

            } else if (v.getId() == R.id.btnminus) {
                IM1.setText("-");
                IM2.setText("-");

                int R1 = Integer.parseInt(Num1.getText().toString());
                int R2 = Integer.parseInt(Num2.getText().toString());
                String R3 = (Num3.getText().toString());

                if ((Num3.getText().toString()) != Dif){
                    int R4 = Integer.parseInt(R3);
                    int RT = R1 - R2 - R4;
                    Result.setText(String.valueOf(RT));
                }
            } else if (v.getId() == R.id.btnMult) {
                IM1.setText("x");
                IM2.setText("x");

                int R1 = Integer.parseInt(Num1.getText().toString());
                int R2 = Integer.parseInt(Num2.getText().toString());
                String R3 = (Num3.getText().toString());

                if ((Num3.getText().toString()) != Dif){
                    int R4 = Integer.parseInt(R3);
                    int RT = R1 * R2 * R4;
                    Result.setText(String.valueOf(RT));
                }
            } else if (v.getId() == R.id.btnDivi) {
                IM1.setText("÷");
                IM2.setText("÷");

                int R1 = Integer.parseInt(Num1.getText().toString());
                int R2 = Integer.parseInt(Num2.getText().toString());
                String R3 = (Num3.getText().toString());

                if ((Num3.getText().toString()) != Dif){
                    int R4 = Integer.parseInt(R3);
                    int RT = R1 / R2 / R4;
                    Result.setText(String.valueOf(RT));
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (Num1.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Ups! Parece que haz dejado un campo vacio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (Num2.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Ups! Parece que haz dejado un campo vacio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (Num3.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Ups! Parece que haz dejado un campo vacio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien el problema cuando dice que se pone de 2 numeros a 3, puedes poner el layout completo? Por cierto tienes 2 layouts imagino uno para landscape y otro para portrait no?

Comment: @solamente En la vista portrait el programa visualiza 2 editText y cuando se cambia a landscape te visualiza 3, similar a las calculadoras android, para sumar, restar, dividir y multiplicar
Sip, son dos, uno /land.
En sí, el problema radica en que el EditText que se pone en la vista landscape afecta también al portrait

Comment: El problema vendrá seguramente de como tendrás colocados los editText ya que cuando lo giras no tendrás suficiente espacio y por esa razón no caben en la pantalla, deberías revisar que elementos utilizas para colocarlos, por eso te comentaba que mostraras el código completo de los layout portrait/landscape

Comment: @solamente Mi sister está utilizando el PC, pero te adjunto las vistas de lo que vendría siento el problema, en la portrait no hace nada cuando pones números, y en la land tienes que borrar lo del editText 3 para que funcione   https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=1exOm_iIzzJuZ3s_wzUqOWAvVB86C9p-0

Comment: ¿Has probado algo parecido a detectar la proporción de la pantalla? Es decir, dependiendo del largo x ancho muestre una cosa u otra (por aquello de evitar el comprobar la orientación.

Comment: @smt Pues en sí, con la vista del EditText no hay problema, porque son 2 archivos de xml distintos para los diferentes modos (horizontal y vertical) el problema es que cuando se ocupa sumar o restar el EditText Num3 influye en la vista portrait y por eso no me deja, adjunté los archivos de cómo es que se ve

Comment: Sigo sin ver que problema tienes y no puedo ver los archivos que comentas que has adjuntado. La forma mas rápida de solventarlo yo creo seria que subieras el proyecto a github y compartirlo es mucho más fácil ver y resolver el problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según lo que planteas, solamente debes colocar los 3 `TextView` en ambas `View`, tanto en el `Potrait` como en el `Landscape`, solo que jugando con que se mostrará según tu pantalla. Ejemplo:

**Potrait:**

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/numero1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Primer numero"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/numero2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="segundo numero"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/numero3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Tercer numero"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:setVisibility="gone" <--- ACÁ LA PROPIEDAD IMPORTANTE
        android:textSize="20dp" />
```

Así estarás mostrando solo 2 `EditText` en la vista vertical, así obtengas el id del mismo en el código java, si esta `"gone"` no estará visible, tiene la función aun, solo que no se verá.

**Landscape:**

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/numero1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Primer numero"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/numero2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="segundo numero"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/numero3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Tercer numero"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
```

Acá como puedes ver no coloque la propiedad, ya que necesito que los 3 se vean.

NOTA: Debes jugar también con el tipo de layout que aplicarás dentro de tu `View` para que puedan verse y adaptarse adecuadamente, me refiero a la aplicación de `LinearLayout` o `RelativeLayout` acá la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout?hl=es-419) acerca de eso.

Comment: Gracias, estuve investigando y encontré el método que buscaba, puse el setVisibility:"gone" y utilizé el num3.getVisibility == View.GONE

Comment: excelente!, que bueno que lo lograras.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que ya veo como puedes resolver tu problema, puedes utilizar el siguiente código para mostrar o ocultar el editText según si es landscape o portrait creo que así evitaras el problema que estas teniendo.

```
int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    Num3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    Num3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: Según comenta en la pregunta, no puede utilizar código que reconozca la orientación. Creo que esto no le valdría, pero es una buena solución como algo general.